# How to parse text in a table format shown to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I want to convert a text file with data in table like format to csv.
The table looks like this

```
name                     type             attribute
------------------ -------------------- -----------=
---------
oscar            dog              can bark and can
roll over
bruno            dog              can bark
buddy            dog              can bark and can
roll over
```

The csv should look like this

```
name,type,attribute
oscar,dog,can bark and can roll over
bruno,dog,can bark
buddy,dog,can bark and can roll over
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can you share the text file or the first 10 rows? Your pasted sample seems malformatted.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that somebody saved the document with `word-wrap` option turned on.

You can try this script to convert the text to DataFrame (I'm supposing the columns are separated by more than two spaces):

```
import re
import pandas as pd


txt = '''name                type              attribute
----------------- ----------------------=
---------------- --------------------------=
oscar                  dog               can bark
and can roll over

bruno                  dog              can bark

buddy                 dog             can bark and can 
roll over'''

is_row = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')
is_dashed_line = re.compile(r'-{3,}')

data = []
for line in map(str.strip, txt.splitlines()):
    if not line or is_dashed_line.search(line):
        continue
    if is_row.search(line):
        data.append( is_row.split(line) )
    else:
        data[-1][-1] += ' ' + line

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    name type                   attribute
0  oscar  dog  can bark and can roll over
1  bruno  dog                    can bark
2  buddy  dog  can bark and can roll over
```